# Fotorama arrows aren't displaying

Tags: javascript, fotorama

I've just installed the Fotorama javascript script. However, when I use data-arrows="true" to enable arrows, which is an attribute you can set in it, they do not display at all.

This is the code with the image links removed:

```
<div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-width="200;" 
data-height="200" data-arrows="true" data-click="true">

<img src="Image 1" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> 
<img src="Image 2" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> 
<img src="Image 3" alt="" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

Has anyone who has used Fotorama had this problem? Or can anyone test this and see if it's just me. You can download the script at: http://fotorama.io/

Here's a demo of how it should work: http://fotorama.io/examples/arrows-click-swipe.html

Thank you.

Comment: Since your question in the 14th here about that library, don't expect an answer...

Comment: lol I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: Can you give us a demo?

Comment: I don't know to much about that library but it looks like the demo also has a reference to jquery.  Do you have that included in your code?

Comment: Removed the ';' from `data-width` and made a fiddle. It shows the arrows when you move the mouse over the image. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/65NQy/1/)

Comment: It worked. Mainly, in Magento Go, you can normally enter your own custom css. However, it seemed even putting it there, none of it was being acknowledged. So I linked to the stylesheet with the following and it fixed it: 
   <link  href="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.2.3/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery 1.8 or later.

**Put `fotorama.png` and `fotorama@2x.png` in the same directory with the `fotorama.css`.**

Remove the `;` symbol from the `data-width` attribute.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

By default to .fotorama__wrap fotorama adds `.fotorama__wrap--no-controls`.

Change `opacity: 0` to 1 in SCSS source

```
.fotorama__wrap--no-controls {
    .fotorama__arr,
    .fotorama__fullscreen-icon {
      opacity: 1;
      &:focus {opacity: 1}
    }
}
```